# Arangodb query for all relations between subset of nodes limited by depth

Tags: arangodb, graph-traversal

For example, I want to query out exactly this graph starting from dave with limit of depth 2
[image]

Now if I want to get the node connected to Dave with depth of 2 I would use

```
For v,c in 0..2 
ANY "persons/dave" knows 
OPTIONS {uniqueVertices: "global",bfs: true }
return v
```

This would return:

- Dave-Bob-Charlie-Eve-Alice (everyone in the graph)

But I do not know how to query to return the correct set of relations which is:

- Eve to Alice **not** missing
- If graph is bigger, Alice-to-someoneelse would **not** be in the result

My current solution below would not return Eve-to-Alice

```
For v,c in 1..2 
ANY "persons/dave" knows 
OPTIONS {uniqueEdges: "global",bfs: true }
return c
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Eve-to-Alice is a third level of traversal if you start at Dave. You can write the query:

```
for v, e, p in 1..3 ANY "persons/dave" knows options {uniqueEdges: "path",bfs: true}
    return {vertex: v, edge: e, path: p}
```

This will give you every edge, including the one between Eve and Alice. Does this answer your question?

If you need to limit this to paths only between second level nodes, you need to create a filter.

Comment: This solutions failed in the second criteria, in which if the graph is bigger, Alice-to-someoneelse would also be returned. I only want the edges between those set of nodes